# Make get api call

Tags: swift, get

I want to link my backend python with my front end ios swift app. I want to call for a get api call. I tried all the answers on stack overflow: like this one:

```
var url : String = "http://google.com?test=toto&test2=titi"
var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
    let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary

    if (jsonResult != nil) {
        // process jsonResult
    } else {
       // couldn't load JSON, look at error
    }
```

but it gave me an error on line 3 saying consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ;

Also, I tried the following: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0,green:200/255.0,blue:100/255.0,alpha:1)

```
    let url = URL(string:"http://127.0.0.1:5000/")!

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
       guard error == nil else {
         print("error calling GET on /todos/1")
         print(error!)
         return
       }// do stuff with response, data & error here
    })
    guard let responseData = data else{
        print("Error: did not receive data")
           return
    }
```

but data in line 11 was not identified

Comment: Instead of posting 2 different code samples I think you should focus on one and explain in more detail what the issue is with it. I strongly suggest you choose the second one since it is based on a more modern version of swift.

Comment: data should be inside of completionHandler block, not outside.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing `task.resume()` in the second snippet (which should be the last line).

Also, this part should go into the `completionHandler`, not outside of it.

```
guard let responseData = data else{
    print("Error: did not receive data")
       return
}
```